# How to use Async task to pause program multiple times

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I know the title is somewhat confusing, my problem is this: I want to "pause" my program multiple times (via a loop) using sleep(ms) and make changes to several buttons that the user has pressed. I understand that changes to the UI can only be made in the main thread, so I am wondering how to convert this code into an Async task. I also remember reading somewhere that Async task can only be called once? If this is so, what other solutions could I look into?

```
View.OnClickListener SimulateButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        for(int j=0;j<169;j++) //169 buttons to click
        {
            if(ClickedPoints[j]!=null) //how I keep track of which buttons has clicked
            {       //clear button color
                Drawable d2 = ClickedPoints[j].getBackground();  
                ClickedPoints[j].invalidateDrawable(d2);  
                d2.clearColorFilter();
            }

        }

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        for(int i=0;i<169;i++)
        {
            if(ClickedPoints[i]!=null)
            {       //change the color after some time
                Simulate(timer, i);
                //clear color again
                Drawable d2 = ClickedPoints[i].getBackground();  
                ClickedPoints[i].invalidateDrawable(d2);  
                d2.clearColorFilter();

            }

        }
}   
};

public void Simulate(Timer timer, final int index)
{
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run() {
            Sim(index);
        }

    }, 1000); //delay for some amount of time, then rehighlight the button
}

private void Sim(int i)
{
    Drawable d1 = ClickedPoints[i].getBackground();  
    PorterDuffColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);  
    d1.setColorFilter(filter);
}
```

Comment: Wait... sorry. But why exactly do you want to do this?? Why not just make the changes immediately?

Comment: My goal is to "simulate" some pattern that the users have created by clicking on a grid on buttons. The clicked buttons will turn red after some amount of time, and then back to clear. The time delay is associated to the project and simulates how long an electron beam is at a point (button). Essentially all of the clicked buttons will blink, sequentially. My apologies for the lack of clarity

Comment: easyest will be to use a Handler where you can `postMessageAtTime`

Comment: or also with a Handler: `postDelayed(...)` But you may want some sort of fade-out effect, so just call `postDelayed(this)` in your Handler again and again, use this to fade out your button color.

Comment: Yeah `AsyncTask` is for running potentially expensive operations in the background... you shouldn't be creating and executing one just for the purpose of pausing an operation for a fraction of a second. You should use a `Handler` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using a Thread to run your background work (and pausing) and a Handler to access the UI thread.

Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#handler) on using handlers with threads.

Comment: Looking through it, will accept answer once I get through everything. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately adapting that tutorial to my code still isn't working. I'm having the same problem as I was before, where the setColorFilter and clearColorFilter calls are causing everything to crash.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to change the UI from your other thread, which would cause a crash. Try using runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { /* Update UI from here */ } }); which will force the changes you want to make to run on the UI Thread.